# Large binary over asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, asmx, webmethod

I am transfering a large zipped text file over the classic asmx web service.
My reason for doing so is that the file's size is 20 MB unzipped, 4MB zipped.

This is the method. I will provide additional information if necessary.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public byte[] Transfer()
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(@"4MBFile.zip");
    }
```

I am using C# and .NET 4. (I changed the initial settings for the project from 2.0 to 4.0).

A webmethod uses a kind of serialization so I guess there will be some overhead.

Am i really transferring only 4MB?
How do I measure this overhead, if there is any?

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be cool..

Comment: Try running fiddler, you should be able to tell exactly how big your transfer is. As CodeCaster says, it depends on which protocol your webmethod is configured to use.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but it's likely because your question isn't clear. Are you asking 'is this the right thing to do?'

Comment: I am sorry. How do i measure it would be an ok question.

Comment: I guess your answer would be _easily_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> XML Web Services expose useful functionality to Web users through a standard Web protocol. In most cases, the protocol used is SOAP.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377918/how-to-serialize-byte-array-to-xml-using-xmlserializer-in-c) shows that the XmlSerializer, used by ASMX Web Services, by default Base64-encodes binary data , so yes, the overhead will be noticable.

> Am I really transfering only 4MB?

What keeps you from monitoring a service call using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp)? It'll tell the exact HTTP response body size.

There [seems to be a solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996427.aspx) by attributing the property as hexBinary, so it won't be Base64-encoded.

Comment: *What keeps you from monitoring a service call using Fiddler?* Not knowing that there is such a thing, and that such a thing is directly applicable here.

Comment: The referred article says: "It is well known that base64 encoded data expands by a factor of 1.33x original size, and that hexadecimal encoded data expands by a factor of 2x" So why is hexBinary better than base64? I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @bjdodo you're right, I don't know what I was thinking.