# issue with Response.OutputStream.Write adding html code in the resulting file

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, outputstream

I read in a text file and try to push it to the browser to prompt a user to download but I'm getting my data plus HTML code inside the file.  What am I screwing up?  Thanks.

```
byte[] eftTextFile = ...calls a method that returns a byte array (does a File.ReadAllBytes on a txt file)
```

Then I try:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", eftTextFile.Length.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(eftTextFile, 0, eftTextFile.Length);
Response.Flush();
```

This is my aspx.cs file and is the result of a button click. which is a simple:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreate" Text="Create" runat="server" OnClick="btnCreate_Click">
```

Comment: Its better to make a handler and use the handler to send the file. Probably here some part of your page already sended to the client. Also after the `Response.Flush();` you must add the `Response.End();` to stop sending data.

Comment: The code snippet that you pasted.. What event-handler/method is it called from? Page_Load? mybutton_Click? Page_Render? knowing at what point in the page lifecycle it is called would help diagnose the problem. Additionally are there any other places in your page you write directly to the response, or do you have custom controls on your page that might be doing so?

Comment: @Aristos +1 Thanks, your input led me to a solution for a related problem :) , however instead of adding Response.End() after Response.Flush() : depending on your requirement (like mine was) ... replace Response.Flush() with Response.End(), this not only sends all buffered content to client but it also stops execution of page and raises EndRequestEvent, [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Just write at the end

```
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using "HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); but that did not work.  The only thing I could get to work was using Response.End().  Not sure why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of your interest:

[Large binary over asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708119/large-binary-over-asmx-web-service)

It uses a web method, which is pretty much as efficient as it can get, and there's very little coding involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to [CompleteRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the end.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"",    fileName));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", eftTextFile.Length.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(eftTextFile, 0, eftTextFile.Length);
Response.Flush();
//now signal the httpapplication to stop processing the request.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Calling CompleteRequest is superior to calling Response.End() in that it shuts the response down correctly and gets around some of the issues in internet explorer brought up in this question:

[IE 10 - File download issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655566/ie-10-file-download-issues)

Comment: I tried using "HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();" but I got the same result, my txt data with html code.  The file is only 1KB in size so it's not large.

Comment: I had a similar issue another time, and it turned out the my anti-virus software (AVG) was intercepting http calls, even to the local machine, and injecting their own code into it. Just something else to try disabling.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be very simple; you have this...

```
attachment;filename
```

...where you should (according to spec) have this:

```
attachment; filename
```

Note the space character.