# Return text from output stream in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, outputstream

I have a scenario where i need to get string as output stream in c#. I need to get those string value in javascript. Following is code

**JS**

```
var timestampUrl : "getTime.aspx" // Used somewhere in plugin. Syntax is fine
```

*Originally was written as var timestampUrl : "getTime.php" but i changed it to work in .aspx also*

**getTime.php code**

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

**getTime.aspx.cs**

```
var ts = ((long)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds) / 1000;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ts.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

But i get the output as

```
1436538190%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%22%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3E%3C/title%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20method=%22post%22%20action=%22getTime.aspx%22%20id=%22form1%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class=%22aspNetHidden%22%3E%3Cinput%20type=%22hidden%22%20name=%22__VIEWSTATE%22%20id=%22__VIEWSTATE%22%20value=%22oyHYMIrhkYo9Ho3QkkQWovQ9tbRhQ2wRTHQfGgw4jJwaPeQsTPcZzR1s5K/dHFoH+p82j3XOogiKTqnH0MB/T9K/8kizxTDiLPwKPNWHHp0=%22%20/%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22aspNetHidden%22%3E%3Cinput%20type=%22hidden%22%20name=%22__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR%22%20id=%22__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR%22%20value=%22EA09725A%22%20/%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/form%3E%3C!--%20Visual%20Studio%20Browser%20Link%20--%3E%3Cscript%20type=%22application/json%22%20id=%22__browserLink_initializationData%22%3E%20%20%20%20%7B%22appName%22:%22InternetExplorer%22,%22requestId%22:%22f532ae409a044422a3178fdad51fb6a0%22%7D%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22http://localhost:62796/df94eb33421548aca703559a9bdf2a2c/browserLink%22%20async=%22async%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3C!--%20End%20Browser%20Link%20--%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

Instead of only `436538190`

What could be the cause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close off the stream.

```
var ts = ((long)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds) / 1000;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ts.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Response.Flush();
//now signal the httpapplication to stop processing the request.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

See: [issue with Response.OutputStream.Write adding html code in the resulting file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391484/issue-with-response-outputstream-write-adding-html-code-in-the-resulting-file)

Comment: I able to do so using `Response.End`. But anyway thanks for guidance.. You can edit your answer if you want