# ObjectSerializer array field of struct

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization, field

Well, i'm working on C# and i'm trying to serialize to XML a struct, and it's working fine with all fields except with a byte array

The code is somthing like this:

```
public struct myStruct
{ 
    int field1;
    string field2;
    byte[] field3;
}

public void function()
{
     myStruct struct = new myStruct();
    /*
        Fields Loads
    */
    string text = ObjectSerializer<myStruct>.ToXml(struct);
    File.WriteAllText(myPath, text);
}
```

After to execute and see my generated .txt all the fields are fine, but i don't have the items of the byte[]
I only have the  tag whit a string like "AQIBA" or something like that

I hope yo can help me

Comment: 1) You need to make all the fields/properties of `myStruct` be public.  Currently none are public so nothing at all will get serialized.  Is that a typo?  2) Can you share the code for `ObjectSerializer<myStruct>.ToXml()`?

Comment: 3) Do you have a precise XML format you are trying to (de)serialize?  4) Can you change from a `struct` to a `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) serializes byte arrays in the w3c standard [`base64Binary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#base64Binary) format.  This is what you are seeing when you see a *string like `"AQIBA"` or something like that* in your XML for the value of `field3`.

In addition [`hexBinary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#hexBinary) is also supported as mentioned in the documentation for [`XmlElementAttribute.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx#Anchor_2) and can be enabled as follows:

```
[XmlElement(DataType = "hexBinary")]
public byte [] field3;
```

Since `base64Binary` is a w3c standard encoding to represent arbitrary binary data, it should be supported by any XML serializer.  Nevertheless, it seems you *must* have your `byte[] field3` array encoded as a repeating set of `<field3>` elements as follows:

```
<myStruct>
  <field1>101</field1>
  <field2>hello world</field2>
  <field3>0</field3>
  <field3>1</field3>
  <field3>2</field3>
  <!--Additional field3 items as required -->
</myStruct>
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to force this purely through [XML serialization attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx).  Instead you will need to add a surrogate array property to `myStruct` as follows:

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;

    [XmlElement("field3")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public ValueWrapper<byte>[] Field3Xml { get { return field3.ToWrapperArray(); } set { field3 = value.FromWrapperArray(); } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[] field3;
}

public struct ValueWrapper<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    [XmlText]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ValueWrapper<T>(T b)
    {
        return new ValueWrapper<T> { Value = b };
    }

    public static implicit operator T(ValueWrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.Value;
    }
}

public static class ValueWrapperExtensions
{
    public static ValueWrapper<T>[] ToWrapperArray<T>(this T[] values) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        return values.Select(b => (ValueWrapper<T>)b).ToArray();
    }

    public static T [] FromWrapperArray<T>(this ValueWrapper<T>[] values) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        return values.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray();
    }
}
```

This will generate the XML you require.  Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5f2gC).

Finally, `XmlSerializer` only serializes **`public`** fields and properties.  Check to make sure the properties of `myStruct` are not `private` or `internal` as is shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My example didn't work properly too.

Take a look to the Microsoft doc.
In examle you will find DataContractAtribute `[XmlElement(DataType = "hexBinary")]`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I understand your corrections and implemented the answer but it isn't still working. In fact, it do the same thing of my original code.
All the fields are saving correctly except the byte[] field
I got 
<field3>AQIDBA==</field3>
i need one by one the elements of the array.
I have readed something about the byte arrays encoding using base 64 in this thead 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377918/how-to-serialize-byte-array-to-xml-using-xmlserializer-in-c
but i don't under stand how to solve it